# Store handshake to use later

Tags: wireshark

I successfully captured my client's 4WHS with airodump-ng and Wireshark is decrypting everthing corectly. I decided to store the 4WHS in a cap file, the idea is that when I do a new capture I don't have to deauth my client again. I want to simply capture the traffic and then merge the 4WHS packets into the capture with Wireshark. Tried that but it doesnt work, after adding the 4WHS the capture is not being decrypted. Why could that be happening?

By the way the 4WHS is from other capture, by that I mean that I stopped the capture got the 4WHS, started another capture stopped it and then merged the files. All that from the same client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all four handshake packets **for the session you're trying to decrypt**, otherwise Wireshark won't be able to decrypt the traffic.
See Wireshark Wiki: [How to Decrypt 802.11](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11): Gotchas
Take a look at the [Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) or [Ask Wireshark](http://ask.wireshark.org/)

Comment: I did, I have them all, 1 2 3 and 4, read my comment, I even decrypted the capture, the question is if I store the four packets in a single capture file, can I then move the four packets into another capture file that hasn't been decrypted? I mean to move the handshake in order to decrypt another capture from the same client.

Comment: If those packets still belong to the same session...; see the Wiki Wireshark  Gotchas.